# How to print a list in a 3 by 3 array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

If I wanted this list

```java
List<Character> Board = Arrays.asList('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
```

to be printed as

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

How exactly would I do that? Any help would be nice.

Comment: Using for loop and `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming exactly 3 x 3 size:

```
for (i=0; i<9; i+=3) {
    for (j=i; j<i+3; j++) {
        System.out.printf(" %c", Board.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Generalizing to work for any N x M is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(Board.get(i * 3 + j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a dynamic separator. The first character is special, in that you want no separator. Otherwise, default to a space. Every third character change it to two newlines. Also, Java naming convention would be `board` (not `Board`). Something like,

```
String sep = "";
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s%c", sep, board.get(i));
    sep = (i + 1) % 3 == 0 ? "\n\n" : " ";
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```